# How to display one component for different api calls in react-native.?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, api, if-statement

Iam new to react-native iam trying to display a single value for two api values the problem is iam getting repeated component calls for two values whereas i want it to be displayed single time only
below is my code

```
 if (item.current== 0 && item.overdue==0 ) {
                    return (
                      <View style={{ flex: 2, alignItems: "center" }}>
                        <Text
                          style={{
                            fontSize: _font(11),
                            color: colours.green,
                          }}
                        >
                          <Icon
                            size={18}
                            color="green"
                            name="checkcircleo"
                            type="AntDesign"
                          />
                          
                        </Text>
                        <Text
                          style={{
                            fontSize: _font(15),
                            color: colours.green,
                            marginTop:10
                          }}
                        >
                         TASKS ARE COMPLETED
                        </Text>
                      </View>
                    );
                  }
                }}
              />
            </View>
          </View>
```

This is my api call output
[here you can see two different objects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z8x9H.png)

And my output is below
[This is my output iam getting two completed alls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2UmXi.jpg)

whereas i want an output like this
[Can anyone tell me how its done](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hgwbT.jpg)

Comment: Can you share parent component code ?

Comment: @OzanManav i cant its too long for stackoverflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are passing 2 values repeatly that cause it render 2 times.
It is better if you add the code section that call the code above.
As my imagnation, your code is like this

```
<Text> Tasks Due <Text> 
{ values.map(item => renderItem(item)}
```

To check , you can add

```
<Text> {item.dairy_name} <Text>
```

in the render, to let you see what value are rendering.

So, render only 1 item, not render the array of values.